# Git: gpg: signing failed: No pinentry on Windows?

Tags: git, gnupg

I am setting up `gpg` on Windows to sign my Git commits. I noticed the error message:

```
gpg: signing failed: No pinentry
gpg: signing failed: No pinentry
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

`pinentry.exe` is in my environment variables. But this error message seems mostly appear only on MacOS machines. Even the UI tool fails to sign/encrypt files

[image]

What is my Windows system missing in order to get rid of this message?

Answer (score 3):

The wrong path was set in `gpg-agent.conf`